# Are there any third party file upload tools to upload files larger than 2GB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So basically I need to upload large files, preferably up to 8GB.

I'm limited by these file upload limits:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- set to max value, max request size is 2GB, takes precedence over IIS -->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    ...

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- set to max value, IIS max length of content is 4GB -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    ...
```

I've looked around a bit, and I've heard that the only way to get past the 2GB limit is to upload the file in segments, but I haven't actually found any tools that can do this. Does anyone know of any?

Comment: You don't need any tools, you know how many bytes there are, just figure out how many different segments you need from that.  Once you upload all the segments combine them and check the checksum of the file.

Comment: Look for "file splitter" on your favorite search engine, you will find several utilities capable of breaking large files into pieces then joining the pieces back together again.

Comment: 8GB is huge. what kind of connection does your users have?

Comment: @Ramhound - do you have any examples of how to do that?

Comment: Just my 2 cents but I think you're crazy to think that you'll be able to successfully get your users to upload 8gb files. With today's internet connections, no chance, maybe in a couple of years...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinRar, 7Zip or WinZip should be able to create compressed files broken up into pieces. If these files are then uploaded, you can put them back together by decompressing the entire archive. You can try using the [7-Zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to compress / split these large files. Using compression you also decrease the upload time and the number of bytes sent.

There may be other similar tools for this, as the comments suggest.

**Edit**: just to make it clear - using any of these compression tools won't obviously give you the ability to upload massive files in one go. They can be used to easily compress and split up large files into several smaller, more manageable pieces which can then be uploaded using the existing limits of the file upload control (or similar 3rd party controls). Using these tools would involve giving a utility to your users that helps with splitting up the file after which they can upload the pieces.

Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) that has links to various commercial uploader tools that you may check out but I'm not familiar with them. It also links to Jeff Atwood's blog entry that makes a case to use a desktop tool to do really large uploads.

Comment: I believe OP is asking for a server side control to receive file uploads from users on a web page.

Comment: I thought byte[] has a int64 length on 64bit.

Comment: @xxbbcc Which basically means that if you chained together more than one array you could circumvent this. If someone did a custom HttpModule for uploading that uses this special big array it would solve the problem? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: @sinni800 That could work, although I think the problem is not the server-side memory, since an upload control doesn't have to hold the entire file in memory. My fault for implying that in my comment to RayCheng - I didn't think it through. I'll delete those comments because they're not useful. I think the real issue is connection stability and the browser - if the connection breaks, the upload will be cancelled by the browser. Also, a server-side upload control cannot do compression, so the upload size will be bigger.

Comment: @RayCheng You may be right - he does have the ASP.NET tag. I don't think it's wise to do this with a server-side control because of the way browsers handle uploads and the lack of compression support. (_This is an edited comment that replaced an earlier comment which contained irrelevant information and was misleading._)

Comment: @xxbbcc Right. I think a better avenue of approaching this problem (in addition to increase the possible upload size) would be resumable uploads. If what he wants is really uploading 8 gb of data, he should have them resumable or split. HTTP PUT allows resuming using content-range, doesn't it?

Comment: @sinni800 Lol man, I don't know _that much_ about HTTP. You could be right about this, although a few articles I found question whether various proxy servers handle this correctly or not. At such huge sizes I can totally see several components breaking down because a lot of code may assume `int` or `uint` for data size limit. I personally wouldn't even try using the browser for something like this, even if it's possible to hack it together. (You seem to be knowledgeable about HTTP, you should write a full answer - the OP may use it.)

Comment: @sinni800 I was thinking about this but I'm not sure how the browser would even handle resumable downloads... I guess it could be handled through AJAX calls but at the end if the browser goes down, progress data is lost, unless the server has some extensive bookkeeping logic that deals with this.

Comment: @xxbbcc I just found out Google already did the work with their browser extensions that are callable through Javascript (named Google Gears). Chrome secretly has it built in and Youtube uses it for uploads. Even though Google really pushed it to be available anywhere you probably can't count on it (it's canceled). HTTP PUT belongs to WebDav, and may not be correctly handled by proxies, right. But I think a basic POST with some special X-header could theoretically fix that. The client could have Flash, Java, Native client, anything.. You'd just have to hope that the client has ONE of them.

Comment: @sinni800 Yes, I agree, using a combination of Flash, Java and a potential standalone client makes this possible (that is, one being available at a given user). The file could be uploaded in small chunks so that a single upload doesn't take too long and if it fails, not a lot of bytes must be resent.

Comment: @xxbbcc I wonder if HTML5 would jump into this and offer native resumable uploads from the <input type="file" /> element or if it would be out of their scope... Wait what: http://steffentchr.dk/post/7454042318/resumable-js The html5 File API already allows something like it. Also this: http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html The server can, with this method, receive chunks of maybe 50 Megabytes and never run out of the POST length limit of 2 GB. BINGO. It would, though, need a modern browser!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to circumvent this limitation of the .NET Framework by implementing chunked uploads using the HTML5 FileApi. This will also implement upload security, if the upload fails the code only has to reupload ONE chunk of X mb (however large it is).

You will have to implement this technique both server and client side.

Here's a blog about the implementation on the client side using Javascript with the HTLM5 FileAPI, XHR v2 and WebWorkers.

http://kongaraju.blogspot.in/2012/07/large-file-upload-more-than-1gb-using.html

This is a codeproject about a FileUploadControl for ASP.NET that understands chunked uploading (circumventing the 2 gb limitation) and resumable uploads. It uses the HTML5 APIs so a modern browser is needed. Firefox 4 and whatever current version of Chrome (so we're at Ver 22 by now? Crazy.) should work. I don't know about Opera right now but Version 12 understand Drag & Drop and Webworkers... So yes, it shouold work.

If the features are not given, the file upload control will revert to normal POSTing of the whole file (2 gb limit).

Comment: I removed the second link because i couldnt find a replacement for it. The first one is okay now